# Difference between bounded and real-valued functions

Tags: functions

We know that a function $f: X\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is real-valued, whereas a function $f: X\mapsto\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is extended real-valued. Finally a function $f:X\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is bounded iff exists $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $|f|<M$ for all $x\in X$. At this point, I ask you, what is the difference between a bounded function and a real-valued function? Are those the same thing?

Moreover given a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge1}$ of extended real-valued functions, we say that the sequence converge pointwise if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ exists and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n\in\mathbb R, \forall x\in\mathbb R$. Would it mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ is bounded too or that it is only real-valued? And in which case can I put $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f$?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a real valued function, but is unbounded.

Comment: Then have I to infer that a real-valued function can be unbounded?  So, at this point,  what is the difference between an extended real-valued function and a simply real-valued function?

Comment: Yes, a real-valued function can be unbounded - mobius gave an example; The difference between extended realvalued and real-valued is an extended real-valued function can take the value $\pminfty$.

Comment: If $X=\mathbb R$ there is no $x$ for which $x=\infty$, so it is unbounded, but not extended real-valued

Comment: Let $f(x)=\tan x$ which is extended real valued.  Define $g(x)=\tan x$ except at odd nmultiples of $\pi/2$, but $g((2n+1)\pi/2)=2n+1$.  Then $g(x)$ is unbounded near odd multiples of $\pi/2$, but not extended real valued because it is an integer at each odd multiple of $\pi/2$

Comment: I finally understood. Thank you very much for your help.